# Rake gives a pile of warnings, but eventually works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, bundler, rbenv

I don't know what the hell happened to my app, it's probably since running `bundle install` lately, but each `rake` command is preceded by a pile of warnings. e.g, running `rake db:migrate` (My project is under `/railsProjects/matal-x`):

```
/home/guy/railsProjects/matal-x/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/version.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant Rake::VERSION
/home/guy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/version.rb:3: warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
/home/guy/railsProjects/matal-x/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Version::MAJOR
/home/guy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: previous definition of MAJOR was here
/home/guy/railsProjects/matal-x/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Version::MINOR
/home/guy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: previous definition of MINOR was here
/home/guy/railsProjects/matal-x/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Version::BUILD
/home/guy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: previous definition of BUILD was here
/home/guy/railsProjects/matal-x/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Version::OTHER
/home/guy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: previous definition of OTHER was here
/home/guy/railsProjects/matal-x/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/version.rb:8: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Version::NUMBERS
/home/guy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/version.rb:8: warning: previous definition of NUMBERS was here
WARNING: Possible conflict with Rake extension: String#ext already exists
WARNING: Possible conflict with Rake extension: String#pathmap already exists
/home/guy/railsProjects/matal-x/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/linked_list.rb:110: warning: already initialized constant Rake::LinkedList::EMPTY
/home/guy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/linked_list.rb:110: warning: previous definition of EMPTY was here
/home/guy/railsProjects/matal-x/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/scope.rb:41: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Scope::EMPTY
/home/guy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/scope.rb:41: warning: previous definition of EMPTY was here
/home/guy/railsProjects/matal-x/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:10: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::RUBY
/home/guy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:10: warning: previous definition of RUBY was here
/home/guy/railsProjects/matal-x/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:109: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::LN_SUPPORTED
/home/guy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:109: warning: previous definition of LN_SUPPORTED was here
/home/guy/railsProjects/matal-x/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:17: warning: already initialized constant Rake::FileUtilsExt::DEFAULT
/home/guy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:17: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT was here
/home/guy/railsProjects/matal-x/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:44: warning: already initialized constant Rake::FileList::ARRAY_METHODS
/home/guy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:44: warning: previous definition of ARRAY_METHODS was here
/home/guy/railsProjects/matal-x/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:47: warning: already initialized constant Rake::FileList::MUST_DEFINE
/home/guy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:47: warning: previous definition of MUST_DEFINE was here
/home/guy/railsProjects/matal-x/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:51: warning: already initialized constant Rake::FileList::MUST_NOT_DEFINE
/home/guy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:51: warning: previous definition of MUST_NOT_DEFINE was here
/home/guy/railsProjects/matal-x/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:55: warning: already initialized constant Rake::FileList::SPECIAL_RETURN
/home/guy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:55: warning: previous definition of SPECIAL_RETURN was here
/home/guy/railsProjects/matal-x/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:61: warning: already initialized constant Rake::FileList::DELEGATING_METHODS
/home/guy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:61: warning: previous definition of DELEGATING_METHODS was here
/home/guy/railsProjects/matal-x/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:86: warning: already initialized constant Rake::FileList::GLOB_PATTERN
/home/guy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:86: warning: previous definition of GLOB_PATTERN was here
/home/guy/railsProjects/matal-x/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:381: warning: already initialized constant Rake::FileList::DEFAULT_IGNORE_PATTERNS
/home/guy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:381: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_IGNORE_PATTERNS was here
/home/guy/railsProjects/matal-x/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:387: warning: already initialized constant Rake::FileList::DEFAULT_IGNORE_PROCS
/home/guy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_list.rb:387: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_IGNORE_PROCS was here
/home/guy/railsProjects/matal-x/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/promise.rb:12: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Promise::NOT_SET
/home/guy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/promise.rb:12: warning: previous definition of NOT_SET was here
/home/guy/railsProjects/matal-x/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:13: warning: already initialized constant Rake::CommandLineOptionError
/home/guy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:13: warning: previous definition of CommandLineOptionError was here
/home/guy/railsProjects/matal-x/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:41: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Application::DEFAULT_RAKEFILES
/home/guy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:41: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_RAKEFILES was here
/home/guy/railsProjects/matal-x/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task_arguments.rb:108: warning: already initialized constant Rake::EMPTY_TASK_ARGS
/home/guy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task_arguments.rb:108: warning: previous definition of EMPTY_TASK_ARGS was here
/home/guy/railsProjects/matal-x/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/invocation_chain.rb:55: warning: already initialized constant Rake::InvocationChain::EMPTY
/home/guy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/invocation_chain.rb:55: warning: previous definition of EMPTY was here
/home/guy/railsProjects/matal-x/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/early_time.rb:21: warning: already initialized constant Rake::EARLY
/home/guy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/early_time.rb:21: warning: previous definition of EARLY was here
/home/guy/railsProjects/matal-x/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/late_time.rb:17: warning: already initialized constant Rake::LATE
/home/guy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/late_time.rb:17: warning: previous definition of LATE was here
/home/guy/railsProjects/matal-x/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Backtrace::SYS_KEYS
/home/guy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:4: warning: previous definition of SYS_KEYS was here
/home/guy/railsProjects/matal-x/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:5: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Backtrace::SYS_PATHS
/home/guy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:5: warning: previous definition of SYS_PATHS was here
/home/guy/railsProjects/matal-x/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:8: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Backtrace::SUPPRESSED_PATHS
/home/guy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:8: warning: previous definition of SUPPRESSED_PATHS was here
/home/guy/railsProjects/matal-x/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:12: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Backtrace::SUPPRESSED_PATHS_RE
/home/guy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:12: warning: previous definition of SUPPRESSED_PATHS_RE was here
/home/guy/railsProjects/matal-x/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:16: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Backtrace::SUPPRESS_PATTERN
/home/guy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:16: warning: previous definition of SUPPRESS_PATTERN was here
/home/guy/railsProjects/matal-x/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake.rb:70: warning: already initialized constant FileList
/home/guy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake.rb:70: warning: previous definition of FileList was here
/home/guy/railsProjects/matal-x/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake.rb:71: warning: already initialized constant RakeFileUtils
/home/guy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake.rb:71: warning: previous definition of RakeFileUtils was here
```

eventually the command is being run (e.i the column is being added to the table) but this is very strange.

I run Rails 4.2.5 over ruby 2.1.1 (using rbenv), so I'm a bit surprised to see gems being installed under 2.1.0, but I'm not sure this has anything to do with my problem since I haven't updated my ruby version for a long time.

I've already tried removing rake using `gem uninstall` and then reinstalling, even got to desperately trying `gem clean` and now nothing works. When I try running `bundle install` or `bundle update` it doesnt' do anything, even though I delete Gemfile.lock.

Any Ideas? reverting to an older commit means about two weeks of work getting lost or at least re-written.

Comment: Is this in dev environment? Make sure that the app doesn't eager load and doesn't cache classes

Comment: yes, this is dev env. What has eager loading in a model/controller to do with it?

Comment: Do you get the errors if you `bundle exec rake task` instead?

Comment: I get similar errors, this time regarding `rb-readline` o_O

Answer (score 2):

Instead of running `rake`, try `bin/rake` (assuming you're starting in your project's root directory). If `bin/rake` is gone for some reason, you could create a new Rails project elsewhere and copying it from there.

On Rails 5, you could also run `rails test` (or `bin/rails test`).

I think it may have something to do with recent versions of bundler which made some breaking changes. You might be able to revert bundler to 1.15.x as well (but I haven't tested this).

Comment: Well, running `bin/rake` was error free, thanks. I'll try reverting bundler to an older version and report back.